# space at top of UIWebView not seen in Firefox or Safari

Tags: css, ios, uiwebview

I have a webpage that I'm trying to view in a UIWebView.

It looks like this at the top (space at top before content starts):

[image]

In desktop safari, it looks like this (no space at top):

[image]

I have the following css for the body tag:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Is there something else that I need to do to remove that spacing? Is there a firebug for mobile safari?

thx

**edit 1**
I also have the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320;height=420;user-scalable=yes;initial-scale=1.0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work try it, if this work please mark it as correct answer

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

Comment: hmm... not doing it. I have this on the body tag and no margin-top on the content

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit of a special case but there was an origin.y value on the UIScreen which I just needed to set to 0 which fixed the issue above.

Here's the relavant code:

```
CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
//webFrame.origin.y += kTopMargin + 39.0;   // leave from the URL input field and its label
webFrame.origin.y=0;
```